# Memory leak - a simple phpinfo() page increases container memory usage

Tags: php, docker, memory-leaks

I have a [PHP Info](https://www.thalasoft.com:83/phpinfo.php) page containing the following:

```
<?php
print(phpinfo());
?>
```

But every time the page is reloaded, a `docker stats` commands shows that  the memory usage goes up by 0.25%

I have custom built the images for `httpd` and `php` as well as `mariadb` and a few others.

The memory percentage does not go down ever. If doing nothing it stays stable and does not go up. Only if sending a request does it go up a bit.

Docker version: 19.03.2

Comment: Does this also happen when you leave out `print()`? `phpinfo()` does not require to be printed.

Comment: @digijay That will just print an extra `1` at the end, since `phpinfo()` returns `TRUE`. It's hard to see how that could affect memory usage.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it was just a guess because I was wondering if the output of `phpinfo()` might get copied by `print()`, and thus causing more ram to be used.

Comment: When PHP uses opcache, it can be that the memory will be freed, when the garbage collector decides to. Try more reloads to check if it will be released.

Comment: @digijay I just checked without the print() statement and it also increases the memory. By the way, even if waiting for a long time, the memory percentage usage doesn't go down.

Comment: Which proccess has increased the memory usage? Apache, php-fpm or Mariadb?

Comment: @KoalaYeung It is the httpd/php process. There is no such php process.

Comment: What is the MPM setting of your Apache? Prefork, worker, or event?

Comment: @KoalaYeung I do not use the `mpm_prefork_module` module.

Comment: One thing to note is that the memory usage increase is even greater (some 2%) when sending a request to my own PHP application.

Comment: [sf] might be a better place to ask this, since it's not really an issue with the specific PHP script.